# Unifying inner classes across different parent instances

Tags: scala, type-projection

EDIT: Added in information about `F[_]`

Here's the setup. We have a parent class which contains a type, and a method which processes a type projection of this, across all parent instances:

```
class Parent[F[_]] {

  // These depend on information from Parent (ie F) so
  // cannot be moved outside
  trait Inner { def execute[A]: F[A] }
  case class Foo(i: Int) extends Inner { ... }
  case class Bar(s: String) extends Inner { ... }

  def process(value: Parent#Inner): Unit = value match {
    case Foo(_) => println("integer")
    case Bar(_) => println("string")
  }

}
```

The problem is that inside the case match, references to `Foo` and `Bar` are `this.Inner`, rather than `Parent#Inner`. So the following fails:

```
val foo = (new Parent[IO]).Foo(5)
val processer = new Parent[IO]
processer.process(foo)  // match error
```

One way around this is to change `def process` to:

```
  def process(value: Parent#Inner): Unit = value.asInstanceOf[this.Inner] match {
    case Foo(_) => println("integer")
    case Bar(_) => println("string")
  }
```

(note the new `.asInstanceOf`).

However, this is unsatisfying.

Beyond extracting `def process` out to a third-party class somewhere, is there a nicer way to achieve our desired behaviour?

EDIT:

The classes unfortunately need to be defined inside `Parent` due to the dependence on the `F[_]`. We could in theory move them outside as the initial answer suggests but this would introduce too much work and variety elsewhere since we would need to parameterise each `Inner` subclass by an `F[_]`

EDIT 2:

One potential solution is to reformulate `process` like this:

```
def process(value: Parent#Inner): Unit = value match {
  case _: Parent[F]#Foo => println("integer")
  case _: Parent[F]#Bar => println("string")
}
```

But this means we cannot use `Foo`s unapply method. The following is invalid:

```
case Parent[F]#Foo(_) => println("integer")
```

In the case where `Foo` is instead for example `Foo[A, B, C](a: A, b: B, c: C)` this would mean the match statement becomes:

```
case _: Parent[F]#Foo[A, B, C] @unchecked => ...
```

which introduces a lot more complexity and potential for failure into the pattern match.

Comment: if you'd use the same instance of Parent for creating the Inner instances and processing them you won't have a problem: val process = new Parent[List]() ;
val foo= process.Foo(5) ;
process.process(foo)

Comment: Yep, that works. However we would like our API more free to allow different parent instances to work with each other more easily. Maybe that's not the best design choice and we should change it, but it's what we have/want at the moment

Comment: @Gesar Regarding "EDIT 2". Why not to write `case _: Parent[F]#Foo[_, _, _] => ...` instead of `case _: Parent[F]#Foo[A, B, C] @unchecked => ...`? Does it work for you?

Comment: Actually I guess in type projection case this plays role similar to `case Foo(_,_,_) => ...` in path-dependent case.

Answer (score 2):

You should write either with path-dependent types

```
class Parent[F[_]] {
  trait Inner {
    def execute[A]: F[A]
  }

  case class Foo(i: Int) extends Inner {
    override def execute[A]: F[A] = ???
  }

  case class Bar(s: String) extends Inner {
    override def execute[A]: F[A] = ???
  }

  def process(value: Inner): Unit = value match {
    case Foo(_) => println("integer")
    case Bar(_) => println("string")
  }
}

val processer = new Parent[IO]
val foo: processer.Inner = processer.Foo(5)
processer.process(foo)
```

or with type projections

```
class Parent[F[_]] {
  trait Inner {
    def execute[A]: F[A]
  }

  case class Foo(i: Int) extends Inner {
    override def execute[A]: F[A] = ???
  }

  case class Bar(s: String) extends Inner {
    override def execute[A]: F[A] = ???
  }

  def process(value: Parent[F]#Inner): Unit = value match {
    case _: Parent[F]#Foo => println("integer")
    case _: Parent[F]#Bar => println("string")
  }
}

val foo: Parent[IO]#Inner = new Parent[IO].Foo(5)
val processer = new Parent[IO]
processer.process(foo)
```

---

Example with parametrized `Foo` without unchecked type matching:

```
class Parent[F[_]] {
  trait Inner {
    def execute[A]: F[A]
  }

  case class Foo[B](i: Int) extends Inner {
    override def execute[A]: F[A] = ???
  }

  case class Bar(s: String) extends Inner {
    override def execute[A]: F[A] = ???
  }

  def process(value: Parent[F]#Inner): Unit = value match {
    case _: Parent[F]#Foo[_] => println("integer")
    case _: Parent[F]#Bar => println("string")
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I feared, either we disallow Parents from interacting with other Parent's members, or we lose the niceness of case classes in the second example's pattern match.

Comment: You should reformulate your question better with more details what you want to achieve. Maybe with some example of "loosing the niceness of case classes".

Comment: I added example with parametrized `Foo` that still works. If you still have pattern matching, which can't be expressed with type patterns, please describe your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type projections in the pattern match:

```
def process(value: Parent[F]#Inner): Unit = value match {
  case _: Parent[F]#Foo => println("integer")
  case _: Parent[F]#Bar => println("string")
}
```

Another approach which does let you use `unapply`:

```
// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here
class Parent[F[_]] { self =>

  // These depend on information from Parent (ie F) so
  // cannot be moved outside
  trait Inner { def parent = self }
  case class Foo(i: Int) extends Inner
  case class Bar(s: String) extends Inner

  def process(value: Parent[F]#Inner): Unit = {
    val parent = value.parent
    value match {
      case parent.Foo(_) => println("integer")
      case parent.Bar(_) => println("string")
    }
  }

}

val foo = (new Parent[List]).Foo(5)
val processer = new Parent[List]
processer.process(foo) // integer
```

You can also use `value.parent.Foo(_)` as a pattern if you make `Inner#parent` a `val`.

Comment: This works, but I think it means you can no longer access `unapply` on `Foo` and `Bar`. This would mean we have to introduce lots of cases of unchecked generic type matching, in the case where `Foo` and `Bar` are parameterised themselves by some type parameter. Swings and roundabouts, and it might be we have to choose between these two options in the end